# AWS - No Puedo mapear un Servicio EFS en mis Instancias

Tags: aws, amazon

Tengo un par de instancias creadas en el mismo VPC.
Cree un EFS para disponer de un "almacen" en el par de instancias, asi mismo al crear la EFS me asegure estar en la misma Region que donde cree las Instancias EC2 y sobre el mismo VPC.

Ya teniendo creado el EFS y abriendolo con la opcion de "Asociar", observo las recomendaciones del comando **mount**, pero al realizarlo en cualquier de las dos instancias EC2 se me queda pensando.... y jamas se monta :'(

Las opciones de Red del recurso EFS tiene una seguridad indicada como "sg-cd669dcb (default)", que al mirarla en los Grupos de Seguridad, miro que los puertos de Entrada y Salida estan 100% abiertos porque dice: **Todo el Trafico** (en ambos).

En fin, aun asi no logro montar el recurso y ya agote mis ideas :'(.... Que me recomiendan?

---

Update 16/06/2021

Para tenner mejor organizado el EFS de AWS, en la parte de seguridad he quitado el "default" y colocado un grupo de seguridad llamado "nfs", el cual configure todo abierto asi:

Grupo de Seguridad > nfs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**a pesar de esto** sigo sin poder montarlo, ni desde una instancia EC2, menos desde mi propio laptop :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La resolucion fue algo complicada desde el punto de vista que Amazon no tiene informacion sobre esto en sus foros ni en su documentacion, ademas de que no se indica por ningun lado a modo de **advertencia** sobre esta accion que les mencionare.

Cuando creas un almacenamiento EFS, le colocas por defecto siempre un nombre ejemplo "misdatos". Desde este momento ya tienes listo tu almacenamiento de archivos para "segun accedeR" via EFS o NFS, pero realmente hay una configuracion que **no esta publica** en su ambiente visual de consola, sino que tienes que Habilitarla en el JSON que miraras en la pesta~a de **Politicas del Sistema de Archivs**.

Este apartado mostrara un JSON que por si *no te dice mucho*, pero **solo y unicamente** cuando pulsar en **EDITAR** notaras que existe una leyenda indicando "No se permite montar la raiz".

Desde este punto tiene 2 opciones:

1. Crear un punto de montaje y este si lo podras montar.
2. Si no quieres puntos de montaje y directo ir  a la Raiz (que es mi caso), debes agregar esta linea.
   `"elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"`

Y listo con **"elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"** ya podras montar la Raiz.

Maldito AWS.... me hiciste perder 2 semana con este problema !